# Returning a singular column from a 2D array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, vbscript

I am trying to make a script that returns a singular column from a 2 dimensional array, which would be used as data to draw various things in Rhino. However, I always encounter an error when attempting to do this, and I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with my code. I have my current function reproduced below:

```
Function ReturnColumn(ByVal col, ByVal array)

Dim colsize, i
colsize = UBound(array, 1)

ReDim vector(colsize)

For i = 0 To colsize
    vector(i) = array(i, col)  
Next

ReturnColumn = vector
End Function
```

This should be a very simple function but for some reason I cannot get it to work. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to declare your array variable with `Dim` before redimensioning it. Additionally, `array` as a variable name might be causing problems, because it is a reserved keyword. Use e.g. `matrix`:

```
Function ReturnColumn(ByVal col, ByVal matrix)
  ' Declare variables
  Dim colsize As Integer
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim vector() As Integer

  ' Redimension the array to the size of the column
  colsize = UBound(matrix, 1)
  ReDim vector(colsize)

  ' Fill the array
  For i = 0 To colsize
    vector(i) = matrix(i, col)  
  Next

  ' Return the array
  ReturnColumn = vector
End Function
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c850dt17(v=vs.84).aspx) says (emphasis mine):

> The `ReDim` statement is used to size or resize a dynamic array that **has already been formally declared** using a `Private`, `Public`, or `Dim` statement with empty parentheses (without dimension subscripts).